# How can I parse a large CDATA string coming from an L5X (XML with L5K inside) file as a List in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, string, list, automation

I have a large CDATA string (below and trimmed for ease of reading) coming from an L5X File containing alarms for a given tag.

```
<![CDATA[[-1,[[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ]],0,0,[[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[16,'Flow Meter Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'CV0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'SC0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'TE0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'TE0022 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[13,'FCV0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'E-Stop Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ]]]>
```

I need to get the index of any element where the length is not 0 (i.e. a description is present) in it's respective array.

My current code (listed below) extracts the CDATA value as a string using XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString(), and does several string splits to extract the descriptions from the CDATA.
I can not figure out a way to get the index of those descriptions in their respective arrays.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

XmlReader rdr = new XmlReader();    
rdr.ReadToFollowing("Data");
    string data = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
    string[] formattedDataList = data.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',');
    foreach (var line in formattedDataList)
    {
        var item = line.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');<br>
        if (item[0] != '[' && item[0] != '0' && item[0] != '0' && item[1] != '$' && item[0] == '\'')
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Split('\'')[1].Split('$')[0]);
        }
    }
```

Any help in getting the index of the descriptions is appreciated!

Comment: One of your splits could be on `],[`

Comment: In C# I can only split on single characters using single quotes

Comment: There are several overloads for `Split`, including one that accepts a string as a delimiter.  https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution lots of people who post Regex is not going to like.  But it works.  I do not think you have all the brackets right.  Made some changes.  See if this works

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;



namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                @"<![CDATA[[-1,[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ]],[0,[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[16,'Flow Meter Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'CV0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'SC0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'TE0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'TE0022 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[13,'FCV0021 Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[12,'E-Stop Fault$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ],[0,'$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00$00'
        ]]]]]>";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Index 1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Index 2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Alarms", typeof(string));

            string[] splitDoubleBrackets = input.Split("]]");

            foreach(string splitDoubleBracket in splitDoubleBrackets)
            {
                string pattern1 = @"\[(?'index1'[-0-9]+),\[(?'data'.*)";
                Match index1Match = Regex.Match(splitDoubleBracket, pattern1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
                if(index1Match.Success)
                {
                    int index1 = int.Parse(index1Match.Groups["index1"].Value);
                    string doubleBracketData = index1Match.Groups["data"].Value;

                    string pattern2 = @"\[(?'index2'[-0-9]+),'(?'data'[^']+)";
                    MatchCollection index2Matches = Regex.Matches(doubleBracketData, pattern2, RegexOptions.Singleline);

                    foreach(Match match in index2Matches.Cast<Match>())
                    {
                        int index2 = int.Parse(match.Groups["index2"].Value);
                        string data2 = match.Groups["data"].Value;

                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { index1, index2, data2 });
                    }
                }
            }



        }
    }
 

}
```

[image]